# Power Bi Drill through

Tags: powerbi

How can I disable drill through for a particular country.
Ex: we have different country like
Japan,
Russia,
France,
Germany
And we don't need drill through for Germany.
So how can I disable this for Germany country.

Comment: I'm sorry, but not way for this feature

Comment: I think I would use two visuals. One with the "drillable" countries and one visual where the drill function is disabled for countries like Germany. Another way would be to take care that germany doesn't have any information on the second layer. Like if the second drill layer is "states", removing all states in case the country is e.g. Germany.